# Create table as value from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to create table from select statement?

For example, I have format table as below:

```
FormatID Label
1         ID
2         Name
3         DOB
```

So I want to create new table with column name ID, Name, DOB.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: What about the datatypes?

Comment: data types for all can be nvarchar

Comment: smells like bad design. creating tables should be done at run time, it should be done at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
-- build the SQL query
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
select @sql = @sql + '[' + Label + '] nvarchar(255), ' from Format order by FormatID
select @sql = 'create table [MyTable] (' + @sql + ')'

-- create the table
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
go

-- lets see if the table actually got created
sp_help MyTable
go
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do ...

```
   declare @sql as varchar( max) ='';

   declare @cln as  varchar( max) ='';

    select @cln =(    SELECT  Label + '  nvarchar(50)  ,   ' from format  FOR XML PATH('') 
                    );
     set @sql = 'create table  tablename  ( '+  @cln  + '  );
 sp_executesql @sql ;
```

Comment: acutally values from Label is varied. So I can't use fixed statement like that :(

Comment: @sandeep rawat, add brackets around column list, otherwise a good answer.

Comment: but it still have comma :(

Comment: it's really a good answer but I still got to work with bracket & comma :(

Answer (score 1):

@sandeep rawat. Thanks, I modified some and i can now got it ;)

```
declare @sql as nvarchar(max) ='';
declare @cln as nvarchar(max) ='';
select @cln =(SELECT REPLACE(label, ' ', '') + ' nvarchar(50),' from format FOR XML PATH('') );
set @cln = substring(@cln,1,len(@cln)-1)            
set @sql = 'create table new_table ('+  @cln + ')';
print @sql
print len(@sql)
exec sp_executesql @sql ;
```

Answer (score -2):

This will help you

```
select FormatID,Label into New_table_Name from Table_Name where 1=0;
```

There was little misunderstanding.
Hope it will help you.

```
create table #Tbl_Format
(FormatId int identity(1,1),
Lebel Varchar(64)
)

insert into #Tbl_Format
values('Id'),('Name'),('DOB')

Declare @Query nvarchar(512)
SET @Query= (SELECT ', ' + Lebel+' NVARCHAR(64)'
            FROM #Tbl_Format 

            FOR XML PATH(''))

SET @Query='CREATE TABLE Table_Name ('+Substring(@Query,2,LEN(@Query))+')'
EXEC (@Query)
```

Thanks